# Arcwise connected components under a retraction on two points

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, path-connected, retraction

> Let $X$ be an Hausdorff space, and let $p,q$ two distinct points. Then if $X$ retracts on $\{ p,q\}$, establish if $X$ has at least two arcwise connected components, or if $X$ has at most two arcwise connected component.

My attemp:
A retraction is a continuous surjective map $$r:X\rightarrow \{p ,q\}$$
such that $r\circ i =\operatorname{id}_{ \{ p,q\}}$. Since $\{ p,q\}$ has the discrete topology, we know that, by continuity and surjectivity, $X$ has at least two connected components. On the other hand, we can't have three or more arcwise connected components, because the continuous image of a continous set is connected, hence there are exactly two connected components. What I don't see is why these connected components are indeed arcwise connected, maybe because I am not using the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff nor the fact that $i\circ r$ is omotopic to $\operatorname{id}_{X}$.

Comment: It most certainly can have 3 (or any number greater than two) components. Consider the discrete space. As for being arcwise connected: yes, Hausdorff space is arcwise connected if and only if it is path connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the other hand, we can't have three or more arcwise connected components, because the continuous image of a continous set is connected, hence there are exactly two connected components.

This gets it backwards - the *pre-images* of a connected set need not be connected, so we cannot conclude that the pre-images of $p$ and $q$ are connected.

As noted in the comments by freakish, the fact that a continuous image of a connected set is connected only tells you that $X$ is not connected, and therefore it has *at least* two connected components.

Next, as you have correctly observed, these components need not be arcwise connected, but that is no matter - since every arcwise component is connected, it is entirely contained in some connected component, and so there are *at least* two arcwise components.  There could of course be more than two, as the example of any discrete space shows.

Finally, the Hausdorff assumption is necessary because to even talk about arcwise components, we need for arc-connectedness to be an equivalence relation, and in general, it need not be (for example, in the [line with a doubled origin](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000083), $0_1$ is arcwise connected to $1$, which in turn is arcwise connected to $0_2$, but $0_1$ and $0_2$ are not arcwise connected to each other). In the Hausdorff case, this issue is not a concern, since arcwise connectedness is the same as path connectedness, and the latter *is* always an equivalence relation.

##### Remark.

Regarding the retraction being homotopic to the identity, that is a stronger condition than simply being a retraction.  If the retraction were homotopic to the identity (a so-called [“deformation retraction”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology))), then you would then have precisely two arcwise components, since the homotopy would provide a path from each point to either $p$ or $q$.

Comment: It's clear, thanks! I have only one question left. If I have only a "weak" retraction, i.e. a map $r:X\rightarrow\{ p,q\}$ such that $r\circ i$ is only homotopic to the identity, then I can conclude again that there are at least two components? Or there can be strange cases where $r$ is constant?

Comment: @Dungessio if $r\circ i$ is homotopic to the identity, then $r\circ i$ is the identity, since the composition’s domain and target are the discrete two point space $\{p,q\}$.  Maybe you instead wanted $i\circ r$ homotopic to the identity?  In that case, though, you would conclude the opposite, namely that there are *at most* two path components, and in fact there are either two path components that are both contractible, or a single path component that is contractible, depending on whether $r$ is surjective vs constant.